# Selecting strings and characters from variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm reading text in from a txt file, and I have to create a username from an email. The email address is in a single variable. The username must be the first letter of the users first name, and their entire last name. For example, joe.bloggs@gmail.com's username would be "jbloggs"

How do I select the first letter from the first name, then the entire last name, and concatenante them into 1 variable? I think I use the cut method but I'm unsure how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: If the address is already in a shell variable, what does the text file have to do with anything?  This matters because `cut` might be a good idea with the file but is very clumsy with the variable (for which there are other ways).

Comment: @DavisHerring, the information is originally being read from a file and stored in variables using this code

`cat FILE`
`while read EMAIL BIRTH GROUPS SHAREDFOLDER`
`do`
``
`done < FILE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mailbox=${EMAIL%@*}
echo ${mailbox:0:1}${mailbox#*.}
```

The first line removes the domain.  The second grabs the initial and then removes the whole first name to leave the last.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "joe.bloggs@gmail.com" |sed -r 's/(^.).*\.(.*)@.*/\1\2/g'
jbloggs
```

Explanation:
 Here the First character is captured in first `()` and last name is captured in second  `()` . Later they are called as `\1` and `\2`. Check backreferencing.

Comment: `^` isn't needed, `.` has to be first character in the line as you have used greedy `.*`.